# IBM Quantum Experience complains "Circuit needs at least one measure." But, the circuit does have one!

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

I want to run this simple test on the IBM quantum computer *ibmq_lima*, but it complains about the measurement. As you can see, there is one "measure". The weird part is that it works if I change the "U" gate to "u3" gate. But, the "U" is a valid gate according to the OpenQASM 2.0 spec!

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[1];
creg c[1];

h q[0];
U(1,2,3) q[0];
measure q[0] -> c[0];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** There is a bug in the composer (already reported to the composer developers) that do no aliases `U` and `u` (neither `CX` and `cx`). You can use Qiskit, either locally or in the *IBM Quantum Lab* to read this totally valid QASM.

```
qasm = """
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[1];
creg c[1];

h q[0];
u(1,2,3) q[0];
measure q[0] -> c[0]; 
"""

circuit = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str(qasm)
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

Qiskit does have the aliasing `U`/`u`  and `CX`/`cx`. For example, you can transpile and works as expected:

```
transpile(circuit, basis_gates=['u', 'h'], optimization_level=0).draw()
```

[image]

---

### Some background

The `U` gate is defined in the [OpenQASM 2.0 specification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03429), together with `CX`, as an *abstract gate*. `U` and `CX` are a universal basis and all the other gates can be defined as a combination of them.

However, they are not meant to be used directly and the composer does not list them as available gates:

[image: available gates]

"*But if it is right there! the last one is a clear `U`*" you are probably saying. And you are not wrong. As [explained by @KAJ226](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16600/1859), gates are usually detonated with capital letters and non-abstract QASM gates use small-case. As a consequence, the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It should have been a lower case `u` instead. That is, something like this:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[1];
creg c[1];

h q[0];
u(1,2,3) q[0];
measure q[0] -> c[0];
```

It should be noted that this is not just for the $U$ gate but other gates as well. They should be in lower case. For instance, the Hadamard gate usually denoted as $H$,but its implementation is `h`. Similarly, $RX, RY, RZ, CX$ have implementation as `rx,ry,rz,cx`. $U_1, U_2, U_3$ have implementation as `u1, u2, u3`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I cannot accept it because it is ambiguous. Your "it" means IBM parser or the OpenQASM spec? The spec clearly indicates the "U" must be used, so IBM violates the spec. If "it" means the spec, its authors should correct the spec; if "it" means IBM parser, IBM should fix the parser.

Comment: Actually, it's not a parser error, but the lack of representation in the composer. The bug is that the composer should "alias" `u` and `U` (and `cx`/`CX`). You are right that yours is valid QASM. Qiskit in the IBM Quantum Lab will read it without any problems.

Comment: For other users, I mark the answer as "Accepted" because the comment of @luciano has answered the question directly.

Comment: Let me give it shape of an answer in that case, so it is clear for future use.